# How to send image via MMS in Android in background .

Tags: android, sms, mms, android-mms

**I am working for an application in which I have to send selected Image Through MMS .
New Android version have sending mms code but not for older version android greater than android v3.0 . How to send MMS for all android version ?**

Comment: can you please post code whatever have try for new version ?